# Block rewrite not working

Tags: magento-1.9

So I am trying to rewrite `_prepareColumns()` function in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Grid` class.

I created a module with a `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jurgis_Gridrewrite>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Jurgis_Gridrewrite>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <Cms_Page_Grid>Jurgis_Gridrewrite_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Page_Grid</Cms_Page_Grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And `app/code/local/Jurgis/Gridrewrite/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/Grid.php`:

```
<?php
class Jurgis_Gridrewrite_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Page_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Grid
{

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        //content
    }

}
?>
```

(My rewrite works if I just place the Mage file in the `local` folder)

My module is active. I cannot spot my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks quite right as far as the code that is posted in the question.

1. Firstly, see if the application has recognized your rewrite by using the below line of code.
   `print_r(Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->xpath('//global//rewrite'));`
2. Make sure to use `return parent::_prepareColumns();` at the end of the _prepareColumns method.

   ```
   protected function _prepareColumns()
   {
       ....../* Your content */

       return parent::_prepareColumns();
   }
   ```

If this piece of information does not help you, could you please post in the content of your `_prepareColumns()` method.

---

Answer : 
`Cms_Page_Grid` in the config.xml should be in lowercase letters.It should be `cms_page_grid`

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's a cool tool I wasn't aware of! Yes my rewrite is recognised. I will post my full method although as I said, it was working when I just place it in the `local/Mage` folder

Comment: I did find my mistake- in the `config.xml`, in the rewrite declaration tag I wrote it as: `Cms_Page_Grid` but it should be all lowercase like: `cms_page_grid`. I accepted your answer because what you showed me made me realize the mistake, If you could add this in your answer for others to see, that would be great.

Comment: Hope xpath tip helps you in the future. Appreciate the self-help you did. I updated my answer.